# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when reading file int struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am reading 3 things into a struct Songs: songtitle, artist, size of file.  I am getting a error when i run the program, tho it looks correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Songs
{
    string title;
    string artist;
    int size;
};

int main ()
{
    int num_songs;

    Songs song[num_songs];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("songlist.txt")

    while (fin.good()) {
        fin >> song[num_songs].title;
        fin >> song[num_songs].artist;
        fin >> song[num_songs].size;
        num_songs++;
    }
    fin.close();

    cout << "welcome to the show" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the program produce `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` when reading the file into a `struct`?

Comment: *"it might be the compiler?"*  ... erm... no.  Also, since this is C++ and not C, use a `std::vector` and save yourself a headache.  You currently create an array of indeterminate size as `num_songs` is not initialized.  Also, reading `num_songs` invokes UB.  Many problems here...

Comment: ah the help here is priceless i am now working it thanks to all and blessings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You program doesn't "look correct", it has a number of errors, detailed in other answers.

Here is a program that correctly reads in the song list. Note that these are four *alternative* methods for reading the file. Choose the one that makes the most sense to you and delete the other three.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Song
{
    std::string title;
    std::string artist;
    int size;
    Song() : size() { }
    Song(const Song& song) :
      title(song.title), artist(song.artist), size(song.size) { }
    Song(std::string title, std::string artist, int size) :
      title(title), artist(artist), size(size) { }
};

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& is, Song& song) {
    return is >> song.title >> song.artist >> song.size;
}

int main ()
{    
   std::vector< Song > songs;

   std::ifstream fin;
   fin.open("songlist.txt");

   // You could read the songs this way:
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Song>(fin),
       std::istream_iterator<Song>(),
       std::back_inserter(songs));

   // Or, if you don't like std::copy, you can do this:
   Song song;
   while(fin >> song)
       songs.push_back(song);

   // Or, if you don't like operator>>(istream, Song), you can do this:
   std::string artist;
   std::string title;
   int size;
   while(fin >> artist >> title >> size)
       songs.push_back(Song(artist, title, size));

   // Or, if you don't like using the constructor:
   while(fin >> artist >> title >> size) {
       Song song;
       song.artist = artist;
       song.title = title;
       song.size = size;
       songs.push_back(song);
    }


    int num_songs = songs.size();
    std::cout << "welcome to the show: " << num_songs << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your code is pretty crazy ... how big is the "song" array?  At the moment you are initialising it to an "undefined" size.  You MUST initalise num_songs.  Failing to do so means it "could" be using any value.  You're getting an access violation because you intialise the array to the size num_songs (we'll take the arbitrary number 70 as an example, though it could literally be any number) and then you begin writing to the array at that same value (which is past the end of the array).  This is an access violation because you subsequently run into memory that your process does not own.  Hence you are *violating* the memory space by trying to use memory you don't have *access* too.

You need to initialise it to a known size so you could parse your file and find out how many songs there are in it.  Then initialise your array and then fill it.

You'd be far better off using an stl vector as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Songs
{
    string title;
    string artist;
    int size;

    Songs() {};
};

int main ()
{    
   std::vector< Songs > song;

   ifstream fin;
   fin.open("songlist.txt")

   while (fin.good()) 
   {
       song.push_back( Songs() );
       fin >> song.back().title;
       fin >> song.back().artist;
       fin >> song.back().size;
   }
   fin.close();

   int num_songs = song.size();

   cout << "welcome to the show" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `istream::good` as a loop condition. It almost always creates buggy code, as it did in this case. (Your program is likely to create an extra, blank, final `song` in the vector.) Prefer `while(fin >> title >> artist >> size) { song.push_back( Song(title, artist, size) ); }`

Answer (score 1):

`Songs song[num_songs];` where is initialization of `num_songs` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
int num_songs;

Songs song[num_songs];
```

That's not legal C++. The array size needs to be a compile-time constant expression.

The GNU compiler has an extension that allows it, but even in GNU, the value of the variable used to define the array's size needs to have a defined value.

As you write into an array with an undefined size, you eventually reach a point in memory where you're not allowed to write, or you overwrite some memory and change the meaning of something else in your program. An access violation is a completely legitimate response to that situation.

You should use a C++ container instead, such as a vector, list, or deque. They can grow dynamically to accommodate however many items you have in your file.