# read structured binary file c++

Tags: c++

Hello I just wrote the following program to create a .dat files by enter some information and display it in the console.
but in the user prompt the program crashes after print "display records" I am sure the read function(ItemFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item),sizeof(Item)) is wrong but I am stucked. help is appreciated.

```
 struct fileOperation
 {
      string ItemDescription;
      int QuantityAtHand;
      float WholeSaleCost;
      float RetailCost;
      int DateAddedtoInventory;

 };
 void DisplayFiles(fileOperation,fstream);
 fileOperation writtenFileInformation(fileOperation);

 fileOperation writtenFileInformation(fileOperation Item)
 {
    cout<<"Please enter inventory description "<<endl;
    cin>>Item.ItemDescription;
    cout<<"Please enter Quantity description "<<endl;
    cin>>Item.QuantityAtHand;
    cout<<"Please enter the whole sale cost "<<endl;
    cin>>Item.WholeSaleCost;
    cout<<"Please enter the retail sale cost"<<endl;
    cin>>Item.RetailCost;
    cout<<"DataAddedtoInventory "<<endl;
    cin>>Item.DateAddedtoInventory;
    return Item;
}

 int main()
 {
   fileOperation Item;
   fileOperation newObject;
   fileOperation Item1;
   int button;
   bool flag;
   flag=true;
   cout<<"This program perform following operations :"<<endl;
   cout<<"Add new records to the file .(press 1)"<<endl;
   cout<<"Displahy new records to the file .(press 2)"<<endl;
   cout<<"Change any Record to the file (press3)"<<endl;
   fstream ItemFile("inventory1.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
   cin>>button;
   if(button==1)
   {
     while(flag)
     {

        newObject=writtenFileInformation(Item);
        cout<<"you have :";
        ItemFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item),sizeof(Item));
        cout<<"Do you wish to continue"<<endl;
        cin>>button;
        if(button!=1)
        {
            flag=false;
        }
        ItemFile.close();
    }

}
else if(button==2)
{

    cout<<"DisplayRecords "<<endl;
    if(!ItemFile)
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file.program aborting.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    ItemFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item),sizeof(Item));
    while(!ItemFile.eof())
    {
        cout<<"Item description is: "<<Item.ItemDescription<<endl;
        cout<<"Quantity at hand is: "<<Item.QuantityAtHand<<endl;
        cout<<"Whole sale cost is: $"<<Item.WholeSaleCost<<endl;
        cout<<"Retail sale cost is: $"<<Item.RetailCost<<endl;
        cout<<"the data this have been added is "<<Item.DateAddedtoInventory<<endl;
        ItemFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item),sizeof(Item));
     }
    ItemFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when reading file int struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422359/status-access-violation-when-reading-file-int-struct).

Comment: Check out [google research on c++ serialization](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s7biU9CAFeWl8weetYD4Dg&gws_rd=ssl#q=c%2B%2B+serialization+stackoverflow).

Comment: @jww Sorry I can't see the obvious relation for the dupe. Though I agree the question deserves closing.

Comment: If you can limit the length of the description, you can use a fixed length null terminated character array for the `ItemDescription`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - the answers in the dup shows how to read in a `struct`, which appears to be what was asked in this question. In particular, Robᵩ's answer. See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) on Meta.

Comment: @jww Well, I've got this one [`Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi), which covers the topic more deeply. I'd still retain to mark it as a dupe for _this particular_ question :-/ ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - no argument from me. As long as he/she is pointed to a duplicate that covers the subject matter, then I'm happy.

Comment: @jww IMHO, the point is to solve the OP's misconception in 1st place here, as [EricZ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25171934/1413395) serves well. The dupes are [one step beyond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnQqYXK21pg) ;) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ItemFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Item),sizeof(Item));
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is wrong
```

You cannot directly persist an object byte by byte if it contains a `std::string` object. It may maintain an internal pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer on heap (where your string data are really stored) which may be dangling after reloaded.

One thing you can do is to grab the data out explicitly (use `c_str()` or `data()` member function) and write them to file instead of the `string` object. Also, pay attention to portability issues like endianness, data size, etc for multi-byte types like `int`(fixed-width integer like `uint32_t` is a choice), if your program is meant to be run on different platforms.

Comment: The first part of this answer is correct: you can't just persist the C++ std::string object as binary.  However, even if you use c_str() to access the actual string bytes, you would still need some kind of marker in the file to denote either the length or the end of the string, so that you know how many bytes to read into the string before you read the int and float members.

Comment: A more robust solution would be to write a simple text data file, where each line of the file is one member of the struct, and the ints and floats are represented as their textual equivalents.  You could use fstream objects to read and write the file in basically the same way you're handling cin and cout; probably without the explanatory text, although adding a label to each line, e.g. "Quantity=6", like in an INI file, would make the file more easily compatible with future versions of the code.  That's a much more "C++" way to do something like this.

Comment: @DanKorn, I'd assume that it's a basic guarantee that OP should know it well. It belongs to a contact that readers and writers of the file should agree on. E.g., how many bytes of an integer, how long is a string, among other format definitions.

Comment: @DanKorn The _most robust_ solution would be, to use a reasonable serialization mechanism, that defines the data layout scheme in 1st place (independent of the representation in various programming languages/OS architectures). I'm using e.g. google [tag:protocol-buffers] very successfully in my production environments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Right. It totally depends on your application. If you're designing the backup store of a distributed DBMS system, you probably don't want to write something like this. You need a well-defined way to format the data, such as what protocol buffer provides.

Comment: Protocol buffers are fine. That's actually a more specific example of what I was suggesting. But I submit that INI files, while perhaps not  offering the same guarantee of schema conformance and validation that protocol buffers or XML or JSON do, are just as programming-language independent, if not more so, since I'm pretty sure there are INI file parsers available in more languages than just the three (Java, C++, and Python) which protocol buffers currently support (though this is a C++ question). But yes, of course the best solution depends on the application.